# How do I create a new column in a dataframe based on conditions of other columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
                             TransactionId   Value
Timestamp                                     
2018-01-07 22:00:00.000         633025      674.87
2018-01-07 22:15:00.000         633025      676.11
2018-01-07 22:30:00.000         633025      677.06
```

I want to create a third column with 3 possible classes based on conditions of the other 2 columns. I tried writing a function below, but it's not working - I don't get a return when I call df.head() after calling the function.

```
b = df.shape[0]
def charger_state(df):
    a = 1
    while a <= b: 
        if df.Value[a]-df.Value[(a-1)] > 0.1 :
            df['Charger State']= "Charging"
        elif df.Value[a]-df.Value[(a-1)] < 0.1 \
        and df['TransactionId'] > 0:
            df['Charger State']= "Not Charging"
        else: 
            df['Charger State']= "Vacant"
    a = a+1
```

The other answers surrounding this topic don't seem to cover 3 classes for the new column, but I am a novice so just might not get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, setup your conditions:

```
c1 = df.Value.sub(df.Value.shift()).gt(0.1)
c2 = df.Value.diff().lt(0.1) & df.TransactionId.gt(0)
```

Now use `np.select`:

```
df.assign(ChargerState=np.select([c1, c2], ['Charging', 'Not Charging'], 'Vacant'))
```

```
                     TransactionId   Value ChargerState
Timestamp
2018-01-07 22:00:00         633025  674.87       Vacant
2018-01-07 22:15:00         633025  676.11     Charging
2018-01-07 22:30:00         633025  677.06     Charging
```

---

You may need to tweak `c1`, because in this example, although it has both a `TransactionId` and a `Value`, it shows up as `Vacant`, because there is no previous row.

One potential option would be to assume that if a device has a `Value` and `TransactionID`, it *has* started charging, which we could accomplish using `fillna` on `c1`:

```
c1 = df.Value.sub(df.Value.shift().fillna(0)).gt(0.1)    # Notice the fillna
c2 = df.Value.diff().lt(0.1) & df.TransactionId.gt(0)

df.assign(ChargerState=np.select([c1, c2], ['Charging', 'Not Charging'], 'Vacant'))
```

```
                     TransactionId   Value ChargerState
Timestamp
2018-01-07 22:00:00         633025  674.87     Charging
2018-01-07 22:15:00         633025  676.11     Charging
2018-01-07 22:30:00         633025  677.06     Charging
```

Comment: why use `sub + shift` instead of `diff`?

Comment: Because of the caveat I mentioned underneath the initial answer, using `diff` won't allow me to tweak `c1` the way that I want.  You are correct however that the initial answer it is better to use `diff`, but wanted to show how the two relate.  I updated `c2` in my answer to use `diff` now

Comment: got it, just curious :)